# Converting diffgram to non diffgram format and save to database any code sample.

Tags: c#, sql

i am working on diffgram xml. that need to be processed and saved into database.

any code sample to process it. because normal xml class not able to process it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It kind of depends on where the diffgram comes from and what you want to do with it.
To load it into a dataset you do

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml("input.xml", XmlReadMode.DiffGram);
```

In case the diffgram is in a file.
Typically you use diffgrams when you need to merge changes to existing data.
In that case you need to load your existing data into the dataSet and then apply the diffgram.

If you just want to save it into a database you could iterate over your table in the dataset using.

```
foreach (var row in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
```

I could update the answer with more details if you supply information on how the diffgram looks and how the table you want to store it in looks.